# Vector tiles - export does not contain all data

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

I came across the possibility of using vector tiles and I'm trying to find my way around. To test the possibilities, in QGIS I tried exporting the layer with the data obtained from OSM to XYZ vector tile format (.pbf files) But when loading these vector tiles, the data is not complete. Where am I making a mistake? Or what do I need to do differently?

I am attaching the files:

- source data [Lsource.gpkg 120kB](http://depositfiles.com/files/18jx5wau9)
- vector tiles [compressed Lvectortiles.zip 81kB](http://depositfiles.com/files/2rk18co0z)
- Input and output data comparison image [LCompare.jpg 38kB](http://depositfiles.com/files/l9tjxbj3m)

[image: Compare]